# Showing the Fox icon on a desktop shortcut

Tags: icons, visual-foxpro

I am having difficulty in making a shortcut which I have installed on a client’s machine appear with the ‘Fox’ icon.
On my own machine I create the exe file myapp.exe, then create a shortcut to myapp.exe and copy it to the desktop.  The shortcut shows with the Fox icon.
I then copy myapp.exe to the client’s machine, and create a shortcut in the same folder.  With Windows Explorer that shortcut shows with the Fox icon.  If however I copy it to the client’s desktop, the shortcut appears with a different icon (a rather general ‘folder’ with 6 coloured rectangles).
But If I then right-click on that shortcut (on the desktop) and click on Properties, Shortcut, the tab shows at the top the ‘Fox’ shortcut icon and the name of the application.  And when I click on ‘Change icon’, the Fox icon is the only one which is offered at first.
Still within properties, I can change the icon (e.g.) to that from Teamviewer.  If I save that, then the shortcut on the users desktop has indeed chanfged to Teamviewer.
Back on my machine, within VFP, I open up the project and look at the ‘Other | Other files’ tab and see that there are a lot of .bmp files, some them icons I have created.  Do I perhaps need to add some icon into that group and then rebuild the exe?
Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you tried opening the project, right clicking, selecting project info, and selecting "attach icon"?  That's how I attach the icons for my apps.

Comment: Thank you Hank, Have tried what you say (on my own development machine), and this has some effect. Just for testing I chose a file about.ico as the icon (a white l.c. ‘i’ on a blue background.)
The file myapp.exe does indeed show in the normal explorer window with the new icon.
I then create a new shortcut on the desktop. Its target is myapp.exe and its ‘Start in” is (as it happens) “C:\Stage2\Larkhill”. When I right-click on the shortcut and go to its shortcut tab, the icon showing is indeed the ‘about’ icon with the little arrow, next to the name I have chosen for the shortcut. However on th

Comment: Andrew, cool, also make sure you build an installation routine for your app and not just to copy it to the target machine...I've discovered that there's a whole lot that windows wants to see that often gets overlooked.